# ManyToMany reflexive relationship with an extra coloumn in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

First of all, sorry for my english. This is my first post.

Im developing an app for a friend that uses JPA (EclipseLink) and i can´t figure out how to make a ManyToMany reflexive relationship with an extra column describing the relationship.

I tried the solution of **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434253/how-to-map-a-manytomany-reflexive-relations-ship-with-extra-coloumn-in-jpa)** (without using a bidirectional relation):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="relationships")
public class Relationship implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "associated_id_one")
    private Person associatedPersonOne;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "associated_id_two")
    private Person associatedPersonTwo;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    //Getters, Setters and constructor
    ...

}
```

But JPA gives me this error: ***The entity has no primary key attribute defined***.

I know i have to specify a primary key but i don´t now how to make a composite primary key with those two foreign key.

Comment: Don't make a composite key. Add an `id` field to your entity, which is autogenerated like for all your other entities.

Comment: Ok, i can do that, but i would like to do it with the foreign keys instead of adding another field. It´s that possible?

Comment: It's possible, but harder to do, much harder to use, less efficient and less consistent. Really, don't do it.

Comment: I see, in that case i will use a single id field and let the foreign keys as they are now. Thanks a lot ;)